# Add Items to a DynamoDB table from a modified json backup

Tags: json, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I made a backup of TableA, and downloaded it, as several .json files that has in each line something like:

```json
 {"Item": {"key_1": {"S":"value 1"}, "key_2": {"N": "2"}, ... }
```

I modified some values, and I want to add those modified datas in a table TableB.

Is there an easy way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

If table B already exists and you just want to add the JSON files to it, then you can use a Lambda function to read the files and insert the items to DynamoDB using `PutItem`/`BatchPutItem`.

Lambda works well for small datasets, however, if you plan to ingest GB's of data, then AWS Glue is best.

If table B is a new table, then you can use the [`Import From S3`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/S3DataImport.HowItWorks.html) functionality released earlier this year.